# stop thread till other complete

Tags: c#, multithreading

How to stop thread till other thread is running. How can i check thread is running and stop thread in c#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from your question, but you may just be after [`Thread.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join.aspx):

```
// This will block until "otherThread" has completed
otherThread.Join();
```